# Including NUnit TestFixture Name in TFS Test Results

Tags: tfs, nunit, build-automation

I have a TFS build definition setup to run the task "Visual Studio Test" using the Nunit3 Test Adapter. This runs successfully and publishes test results. However, neither the TestFixture name or the Test's Fully Qualified Name are available in the test reuslts. This makes it difficult to determine what exactly what test failed without using lengthy test names.

Is there a way to include the Test Fixture names in the published test results from the build?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the Tests summary tab of your build. It shows the detail information of test results of your Nunit3 tests.

You could use the Filter to find out those Failed or Succeeded tests.

You could also click the link in the picture below to check detail data for this test run.
[image]

Comment: I looked through the "Group By" and "Outcome" options again on the Test Results page shown above and none of the options show the Test Fixture name or FQDN. The listing only show's the test's method name.

Comment: I also opened the Test Summary by clicking on the test, and neither the Test Fixture name or FQDN are shown. I forgot to mention this in my previous comment.

Comment: @mike9182 The Test Fixture name is not included in the Test summary page because it doesn't included in the test result file, so TFS can't get it.